# django admin jQueryUI dialog

Tags: django, django-admin, jquery-ui-dialog

Well, I have a django admin site project and I want to add a simple dialog on one of my change_form template.

I add the following code:

Open button that will open the dialog:

```
<button id='open_dialog' onclick='javascript:$( "#comfirm_dialog" ).dialog("open");'>open</button>
```

The dialog initialization code:

```
<script>
(function($){
$( "#comfirm_dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 450,
    width: 550,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Add": function(){},
        Cancel: function() {$( this ).dialog( "close" );}
    },
    show: {
      effect: "blind",
      duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "explode",
      duration: 1000
    }
});
})(django.jQuery)

</script>
```

The dialog itself:

```
<div id='comfirm_dialog' title='Comfirmation'>
    This is a dialog.
</div>
```

When I click the 'Open' button, nothing happened but with one error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'dialog' "
```

I did some research and found out this may due to many reasons.

One of the most common one is that I may include Jquery twice somewhere.
However, I don't think I did it. I only declare that I am using 'django.jQuery' in 'script' tag.

Does any one know what may be the reason in my case?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: For update,

I try to include 'jquery-ui', then I got 'Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined'

Then I try to include jquery (which I think I should not do it twice, since I have used (django.jQuery).) And I got the same error that "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'dialog' "

Comment: did you include reference for jquery and jquery-ui in the file ?

Comment: personally? No. I assume django will do it for me. I din't include jquery or jquery-ui at anywhere

Comment: django wont do it for you. You should have included `jquery` some where or the error would have been `$` is undefined. Now, make sure jquery-ui is there too

Comment: However, I have specify that (django.jQuery). I assume that should include Jquery right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Replace

```
<button id='open_dialog' onclick='javascript:$( "#comfirm_dialog" ).dialog("open");'>open</button>
```

to

```
<button id='open_dialog'>open</button>
```

and

```
$(function(){
    $('#open_dialog').click(function(){
        $("#comfirm_dialog").dialog('open'); 
    });
})
```

Also, make sure you have included `jquery-ui` source in the template

Comment: actually, I was using your approach. I mean '.click' method. I change to onclick because I wanna make the code simpler. BTW, it dosen't work in either way.

Comment: ok.. when you do a view source, do you see the js library for jquery-ui included?

Comment: Only thing is that I try to include jquery-ui in my template: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>. Then I got that 'Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined'

Comment: Oh.. that is wierd. You should got that earlier. Anyways, include the jquery library too.

Comment: Yes, I did. Then I go back to the start. "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'dialog' "

Comment: Ok..That is wierd. Also make sure you do not reference the jquery-ui twice

Comment: Btw, is there any way to check all my includings in browser>

Comment: yeah - in chrome, right click > view source.. You will see all the included js in the head section

Comment: I will try. However, I wonder whether I will see the including from django

Comment: Well, I got it. You are right. I should include jQuery-ui. However, I should also include jQuery! The point is that (django.jQuery) will include jQuery 1.4.2, but I think I need 1.8.3 at least. So I manually include jquery 1.8.3 and jquery-ui 1.9.2. And it works!

Answer (score 2):

Using Django 2.0.2 the following solved the problem (thank you, [mrts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258772/mrts), for sorting it out):

- [Download jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/download/)
- Copy files `jquery-ui.{structure}.min.{css,js}`, `jquery-ui.theme.min.css` and folder `images` to `/static/jquery-ui` (or any other `static` directory)
- Open `jquery-ui.min.js` and add the following line at the beginning of the file:

  `jQuery = jQuery || django.jQuery.noConflict(false);`
- Add `js` and `css` files to your `ModelAdmin` `Meta` class:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        js = (
            'jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js',
        )
        css = {
            'all': (
                'jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css',
                'jquery-ui/jquery-ui.structure.min.css',
                'jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.min.css',
            )
        }
```

The cause of the problem was that `jquery-ui.min.js` did not know, how jQuery is accessible in Django. By explicitly defining `jQuery` variable, the proplem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and in my case, the issue was different.

The order of JS was different (I know that's the first thing you check but I was almost sure that that was not the case, but it was). The js calling the dialog was called before jqueryUI library was called.

I was inheriting a template and using {{super.block}} to inherit code from the block as well to the template. I had to move {{super.block}} at the end of the block which solved the issue. The js calling the dialog was declared in the Media class in Django's admin.py. I spent more than an hour to figure it out. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me:

1) Download latest stable release of jQuery UI [Download jQuery UI 1.12.1](https://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.12.1.zip)

2) Copy above file into static assets dir and replace the following line

```
(function( factory ) {
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {

    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define([ "jquery" ], factory );
} else {

    // Browser globals
    factory( jQuery ); <--- REPLACE HERE ----
}
```

with:

```
(function( factory ) {
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {

    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define([ "jquery" ], factory );
} else {

    // Browser globals
    factory( django.jQuery ); <--- REPLACE ----
}
```

3) In your ModelAdmin class add media files:

```
    class Media:
    js = (
        'app/js/jquery_ui.js',
        'app/js/custom.js',  
    )
```