# How should images used in jquery-ui be loaded in django admin?

Tags: django, jquery-ui, django-admin

I added an action to django admin which requieres a modal and some javascript interaction. I used jquery-ui for the modal and was able to load it following this instructions:
[django admin jQueryUI dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717835/django-admin-jqueryui-dialog)

However, the modal has a broken image (the closing button). The question is how can I reference that image so jquery-ui can find it.

I put the images from jquery-ui library on the same folder where I put the .js and .css files I'm using for the action.

The close image of the modal is broken, trying to find it on
`http://localhost:8000/static/admin/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/images/ui-icons_777777_256x240.png`

The project path is
`static/admin/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/images/ui-icons_777777_256x240.png`

**update**
I moved the image to `static/admin/images/ui-icons_777777_256x240.png`, stoped the server and ran `python3 manage.py collectstatic`, but is still broken.

The current code I have for referencing the assets is:

admin.py

```py
   class ReservationBaseAdmin:
    list_display = (..., 'action')
    # some more code (...)


    # Here I reference the jquery-ui library and the js code I wrote for the action
    class Media:
        css = {
            "all": ("admin/css/tables.css", 'admin/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css', 'static/admin/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.structure.min.css')
        }
        js = (
'admin/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js',
'admin/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.structure.min.css', 'admin/js/front_iframe.js", "admin/js/force_sync.js'
)

    # some more code (...)

    def action(self, obj):
        front = env('FRONT_URL')
        url = reverse('admin:traveller_traveller_change', args=[obj.traveller.pk])
        edit_button = format_html('<a class="button front_link" data-front="{}" target="_blank" href="{}">Ver Perfil</a>', front, url)
        refresh_button = format_html('<a class="button force_sync" data-confirmation-number="{}" >Forzar sincronización</a>', obj.reservation.confirmation_number)
        return edit_button +  refresh_button
    action.short_description = "Acciones"
```

static/admin/js/force_sync.js

```js
$(function() {
    const syncService = (confirmationNumber) => {

      //... some code
    };

    const makeDialogs = () => {
      const ok = document.createElement('div');
      const err = document.createElement('div');
      //... some code
      document.body.appendChild(ok);
      document.body.appendChild(err);
      $("#okDialog").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,  
      });
      $("#errorDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,  
    });
    }

    $(document).ready(
      /** Gatilla la syncronización automática para una reserva
       */

      function forceSync () {
        makeDialogs();
        $('.force_sync').click(function () {
          //... some code
          syncService(confirmationNumber)
            .then((res) => {
              $( "#okDialog" ).dialog('open'); //--> Here modal dialog shows and works fine except for the broken image for closing the dialog.
            },      //... some code
            });
         });
    });
});
```

I expect the browser to be able to find the image.

Comment: In your urls.py have you added the `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` as shown here: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)